# How to match 'fancy' punctuation with RegEx in Python in a file in cp1251 encoding?

Tags: python, regex, encoding

So I've been trying for quite a bit to match the main English text on the page: http://en365.ru/doctor.htm .  I stored the page with urllib and on my machine it has cp1251 encoding.

I'm using the regex:

```
PARAGRAPH = r">([A-Z]\s?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-'’;&—]+[\s\t]*\n?)+[\.!\?,;:—\%]?\.{0,2}[\s\t]*\n?)+)"
par_pat = re.compile(PARAGRAPH, re.I|re.M|re.U)
```

where I include '’' and '—' literally.

And it only matches up to: 
"*that it*" 
where the full sentece is: 
"*that it’s hard to count them.*"

Same for a similar situation with '—' in another file. 
How to match them?

==========================================

Edit:

I tried to add fixes according to Olaf's comment, but no luck so far. 
To keep it simplier, I tried the following:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
import re
import codecs

pat = r'’'     # pat = '’' or pat = '\x92' gives the same effect 
print  r       #prints some whatever symbol 
par_pat = re.compile(s, re.I|re.M|re.U)

fin =  codecs.open(FN, encoding = 'cp1251', errors ='replace')      
page = fin.read()
# page contains string "that it’s hard to count them."      

pars = par_pat.findall(page)     # outputs []
```

Can it be in fact another symbol (e.g., not '\x92'), or should I decode/encode anything else?

============================================

Edit as a comment to my solution:

The answer I offer is still more of a 'work-around' rather than a thoughtful solution. I still appreciate other suggestions and explanations on what encodings should go where.

Comment: what are you trying to extract?This will get the text from the page , you can add more to the regex http://pastebin.com/GhE24idq. The encoding also does not seem to be cp1251

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, I am extracting the text indeed, and I've just started looking at  BeautifulSoup today. However, the text is not neccessarily in <td> tags. I will look into how to include all possibel tags that may contain a text fragment. Yet pure enumeration of tags loses generality compared to pure regex solution.  |Regarding the encoding, I actually first store the entire web pages. So when I checked the encoding in a text edito,r it was Windows-1251.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the encoding of the various parts, python source code/regular expression and the text you're trying to match. The source code will be interpreted as ASCII or Unicode and the text is encoded in CP1251.

You can use an [encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) for the python source code near the top of your code if it is not ASCII

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
```

or encode the regular expression with a hex code, e.g. `’` will become `\x92` and `—` will be `\x97`

```
PARAGRAPH = r">([A-Z]\s?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-'\x92;&\x92]+[\s\t]*\n?)+[\.!\?,;:\x97\%]?\.{0,2}[\s\t]*\n?)+)"
```

---

Full version (source encoding):

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-

import re
import sys
import codecs

PARAGRAPH = r">([A-Z]\s?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-'’;&—]+[\s\t]*\n?)+[\.!\?,;:—\%]?\.{0,2}[\s\t]*\n?)+)"
par_pat = re.compile(PARAGRAPH, re.I|re.M|re.U)

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
text = f.read()
m = re.findall(par_pat, text)
for s in m:
    print s
```

Full version (special characters as hex):

```
import re
import sys
import codecs

PARAGRAPH = r">([A-Z]\s?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-'\x92;&\x97]+[\s\t]*\n?)+[\.!\?,;:\x97\%]?\.{0,2}[\s\t]*\n?)+)"
par_pat = re.compile(PARAGRAPH, re.I|re.M|re.U)

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
text = f.read()
m = re.findall(par_pat, text)
for s in m:
    print s
```

Both versions are the same, they only differ in the encoding of `PARAGRAPH` and how the source code is interpreted. First source is read with encoding cp1251 and second source is read with the default: ASCII.

Comment: could you be more specific on how to put it correctly? I described my attempts in the question edit.

Comment: I tried the 1st option and it worked for all texts. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that's how it finally worked for me:

```
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
import re
import codecs 

dash = '—'.decode('cp1251')    
text = """ But suppose ' you get an infection—appendicitis, for 
        example. """.decode('cp1251')

dash_pat = re.compile(dash, re.I|re.M|re.U)

pars = dash_pat.findall(text)
for p in pars: 
    print unicode(p)
```

And for the file version (given the same encoding and imports):

```
s = '’'.decode('cp1251')
fin =  codecs.open(FN, encoding = 'cp1251', errors ='replace')      
page = fin.read()

pars = par_pat.findall(page)
for p in pars: 
    print unicode(p)
```